# R: Count instances with multiple conditions

Tags: r, count, data.table

I'm analysing a dataset in R.

Here's the code to generate a toy version of the dataset:

---

```
# Sample dataset
m.data <- data.table(
  f.41272.0.0 = c("G451", "A488", "A113", "A559", "R151", "A842"),
  f.41282.0.0 = c("2007-08-07", "2021-08-07", "2016-12-20", "2019-03-06", "1999-08-03", "2000-09-27"),
  f.41272.0.1 = c("K633", "G451", "A143", "G451", "R172", "F121"),
  f.41282.0.1 = c("2005-07-28", "2010-10-05", "2016-12-20", "2018-06-13", "2004-02-25", "2001-08-06"),
  date_range_start = c("2002-05-13", "2019-08-06", "2015-11-02", "2017-08-08", "1998-11-02", "1998-09-27"),
  date_range_end = c("2003-11-13", "2021-02-06", "2017-05-02", "2019-02-08", "2000-05-02", "2000-03-27")
)

# Vector of targeted OPCS codes
opcs_anaesthetist <- c("G451", "A143", "A113")
```

---

The columns starting f.41272 are OPCS codes. The columns starting f.41282 are the dates of those ICD codes. Each row may have more than one OPCS code and corresponding date, so there is f.41272.0.0 and f.41282.0.0, and then f.41272.0.1 and f.41282.0.1, and so on. For example, in row 1, the ICD code G451 has a date G451.

Each row also has a date range, given in columns date_range_start and date_range_end.

I want to calculate, for each row, the number of times a specific set of OPCS codes appears within the date range. These OPCS codes are contained in the vector opcs_anaesthetist, as shown above. This count should then be stored in a new column.

Looking at the dataset manually, the result should be 2 for row 3, 1 for row 4, and 0 for the other rows. My actual dataset has many more rows so doing it manually isn't feasible, hence the need for code.

I have tried the below code:

---

```
# Convert date columns to actual Date objects
date_cols <- grep("^f\\.41282", names(m.data), value = TRUE)
m.data[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), .SDcols = date_cols]

# Create a function to count instances of target OPCS codes within a date range
count_opcs_in_range <- function(opcs_col, date_col, start_date, end_date, opcs_anaesthetist) {
  count <- sum(opcs_col %in% opcs_anaesthetist & date_col >= start_date & date_col <= end_date)
  return(count)
}

# Apply the function to each row
m.data[, opcs_count := mapply(
  count_opcs_in_range,
  mget(grep("^f\\.41272", names(m.data), value = TRUE)),
  mget(date_cols),
  date_range_start,
  date_range_end,
  MoreArgs = list(opcs_anaesthetist = opcs_anaesthetist)
)]
```

---

However, this gives me a result of 1 for rows 3 and 4, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. The data is not "large" and you're okay with `melt`ing and rejoining; and
2. The `date_range_start` and `date_range_end` pairs are guaranteed unique ...

```r
tmp <- melt(m.data, id.vars=c("date_range_start", "date_range_end"), 
            measure.vars=patterns(f.41272 = "^f.41272", f.41282 = "^f.41282")
  )[, .(opcs_count = sum(f.41272 %in% opcs_anaesthetist &
                         between(f.41282, date_range_start, date_range_end))), 
    by = .(date_range_start, date_range_end)]
tmp
#    date_range_start date_range_end opcs_count
#              <Date>         <Date>      <int>
# 1:       2002-05-13     2003-11-13          0
# 2:       2019-08-06     2021-02-06          0
# 3:       2015-11-02     2017-05-02          2
# 4:       2017-08-08     2019-02-08          1
# 5:       1998-11-02     2000-05-02          0
# 6:       1998-09-27     2000-03-27          0
m.data[tmp, opcs_count := i.opcs_count, on = .(date_range_start, date_range_end)]
#    f.41272.0.0 f.41282.0.0 f.41272.0.1 f.41282.0.1 date_range_start date_range_end opcs_count
#         <char>      <Date>      <char>      <Date>           <Date>         <Date>      <int>
# 1:        G451  2007-08-07        K633  2005-07-28       2002-05-13     2003-11-13          0
# 2:        A488  2021-08-07        G451  2010-10-05       2019-08-06     2021-02-06          0
# 3:        A113  2016-12-20        A143  2016-12-20       2015-11-02     2017-05-02          2
# 4:        A559  2019-03-06        G451  2018-06-13       2017-08-08     2019-02-08          1
# 5:        R151  1999-08-03        R172  2004-02-25       1998-11-02     2000-05-02          0
# 6:        A842  2000-09-27        F121  2001-08-06       1998-09-27     2000-03-27          0
```

If assumption #2 (unique pairs) is not true, then we can work around that by preassigning a unique row id (i.e., `m.data[, id := .I]`) and including that `id` in the `by=`/`on=` arguments.